# Page elements and events destruction after ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is a general question.

I use ajax request to reload the whole page and insert the response in body tag.

Then required elements are constructed and events are added to them using mootools.

I wonder what happens to these elements and events after next request.

**Is it necessary to destruct constructed elements and events manually or do they destruct as they are removed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search I found out there is no way to destroy elements created from JS, and if an element is removed it's considered as garbage. It's up to engine to collect garbage, and it decide to it when!